# Stretching on curve modifier

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I created this building and I'm trying to use the curve modifier along the edge of the roof. It mostly works fine, but I noticed that there is some bad stretching along the sides (see the screengrab).

I created the curve by taking the edge ring of vertexes from the roof, duplicating and separating them, and then converting the resulting ring of vertexes into a curve. I did this in order to create a curve that followed in the line of the roof edge.

https://ibb.co/Pw7wk9b

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: I'm not sure using the curve modifier is the simplest solution, but maybe show the wireframe or even share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Is the scale of your curve Ctrl-A > applied?

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has posted so far. Here is the .blend file while I try some of the solutions. https://mega.nz/file/dgw2TaQL#HUmumrOAR4CRoDiFfqsfujJzqWVbxLAircVHzdIR1Pg